# shape.Parent doesn't return Slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In most cases `shape.Parent` is the slide that contains the shape.

However, if you try to delete a a group and then press on undo (the shapes will reappear) but the child shapes will throw exception for both `.Parent` and `.ParentGroup`.

How can I find out the slide ID of a shape in the case above?

Answer (score 0):

I did your instructions and didn't have any problems. I added two shapes to an emtpy blank slide and and then deleted them both at the same time and then did <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>. then I ran this in the immediate window -

```
?ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Parent.SlideIndex
```

And it worked and showed a value of 1.

So then I thought you had these as a group, so i grouped the two shapes and did the same as above. And it worked just fine.

Comment: it was in the case of a group.
Are you using PowerPoint 2007? I checked it on this version.

Comment: I am using PPT 2007 and PPT 2010, it works on both of them. What do you get when you run `MsgBox ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Parent.SlideIndex` ?

Comment: I have the same problem as Dudi has, and your suggestion does not solve. What I need is to know Slide Id, not Slide Index.

Comment: @chipbk10
The Shape.Parent will return you a slide object,
So with that you can get SlideIndex or SlideId or any property of Slide object, which shouldn't be an issue for you.